# Splitting up a field in OUTLOOK

Tags: vba, outlook

Basically the script below works along with a rule in OUTLOOK.  When I receive the email it saves the PDF attachment.  The problem I am having is I want to change the file name (objAtt.SaveAsFile).  The file name that it comes in as is something like “userid.jobname.JOB22979……..”.  I would like to save the file using the second node (jobname in this case), followed by the date and time.  I believe I can get the file name from object objAtt.DisplayName, but I don’t know how to pick up just the second node in the file name.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm-ss")


saveFolder = "c:\users\xxxxxx\USER\documents\email\"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
     objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & "print.pdf"
     Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Split` to pull out the 2nd token;

```
DisplayName = "userid.jobname.JOB22979.blah"

job = Split(DisplayName & ".", ".")(1)

If Len(job) > 0 Then
    job = job & "_" & Format$(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm-ss") & "_print.pdf"
Else
    '// no match, use original
    job = DisplayName
End If

objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & job
```

Comment: This code works perfectly!!!!  I'm still trying to get DisplayName = objAtt.DisplayName somehow, so that I can get the correct jobname